# Share contract - Deeplink UWP

Tags: share, uwp, deep-linking

I share an content of page, like image and text and it's work fine.

But i try ti share link for when someone click, navigate to a my UWP in a page of content shared before.

Like "Click here": this have a link to navigate for my app installed in uwp.

For navigate to my page I need to pass parameters, such as:

```
 ((App)(App.Current)).NavigationService.Navigate<MyPage>(Parameters.ToString());
```

I dont have any idea to do this. :(

someone help me please?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly; you want to supply a link which will open your UWP app and open a "previously shared" page.

To be able to do this you'll need to register to handle uri activation. You'll have to register a protocoll for your app, for example `myawesomeapp:`.

Then you can pass some additional parameters when someone click the link: `myawsomeapp://navto=sharehistory&showitem=2`.

Lastly your apps need to handle when it's launched from a uri in `OnActivated`:

```
  protected override void OnActivated(IActivatedEventArgs args)
  {
      if (args.Kind == ActivationKind.Protocol)
      {
         ProtocolActivatedEventArgs eventArgs = args as ProtocolActivatedEventArgs;
         // TODO: Handle URI activation
         // The received URI is eventArgs.Uri.AbsoluteUri
      }
   }
```

You can read the docs [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/handle-uri-activation?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: Jon, thanks , I will try to implement. Another question if you know: When I try to share text and image for Facebook (UWP), the text doesn't appear on share post.

Have any problem? Facebook UWP not allow to share text on posts from UWP apps?

Thanks

Comment: I haven't tried sharing to Facebook, but it might be something in their implementation. If sharing image and text works with the email app, then I'm guessing it should work with Facebook too.